# Failed to install PyTables

Tags: python, cython, hdf5, bzip2, pytables

I'm trying to install PyTables using either `easy_install` or `pip` but both attempts end with the same error:

> `error: Command "gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DNDEBUG=1 -DHAVE_LZO2_LIB=1 -DHAVE_BZ2_LIB=1 -Iblosc -I/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/H5ARRAY.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/H5ARRAY.o -Isrc -DH5_USE_16_API"  failed with exit status 1`

I have all dependencies installed.

- Found numexpr 1.4.2 package installed.
- Found Cython 0.14.1 package installed.
- Found HDF5 headers at `/usr/include`, library at `/usr/lib`.
- Found LZO 2 headers at `/usr/include`, library at `/usr/lib`.
- Skipping detection of LZO 1 since LZO 2 has already been found.
- Found bzip2 headers at `/usr/local/include`, library at `/usr/local/lib`.

but there is still a warning:

> `.. WARNING:: Could not find the bzip2 runtime. The bzip2 shared library was *not* found in the default library paths. In case of runtime problems, please remember to install it.`

Is it possible that this warning prevents successfully installing PyTables?

Comment: Are there any other error messages than the one you included? "failed with exit status 1" just says that the command failed, not why. There should be an error message before it, or a way to make one appear.

Comment: Thank you Inerdial for your reply, I found this:                   In file included from /usr/include/hdf5.h:24:0,
                 from src/H5ATTR.h:19,
                 from src/H5ARRAY.c:1:
/usr/include/H5public.h:57:20: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Comment: You probably need to install http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/overview/mvapich2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add this:

```
-I/usr/include/mpi
```